# Count a column by another distinct column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I want to count sum of certain column by another distinct column

The table that I have looks like this

| date | user | id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/23 | name | id1 | 1 |
| 5/23 | name | id2 | 0.5 |
| 5/23 | name | id2 | 0.2 |
| 5/23 | name 2 | id1 | 2 |

expected result would be:

| date | user | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/23 | name | 1.5 |
| 5/23 | name 2 | 2 |

right now I have

```
select 
, date
, name
, count(distinct id)

from table


group by
  date
  , name
```

which results in just counting unique ids as 1, without assigned weight

| date | user | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/23 | name | 2 |
| 5/23 | name 2 | 2 |

On any date, per ID there might be records of multiple user actions, which all have assigned different weight. I want to count the sum of these actions by user for all dates, for all the unique IDs. So if he has performed an action with a weight of 0.5 and 0.2 on certain date for certain ID, it'd only count max weight, which would be 0.5. But if he has also performed another action on the same day on another ID, say with weight of 0.7, the end result that I'd want to see for that date would be 0.7+0.5, which is 1.2

Comment: What is the logic for the arithmetic?

Comment: I've updated the OP. Hopefully it makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming below :

[image]

Code:

[image]

Result :

[image]

I hope it is correct for the given scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm . . . it seems you want the maximum per date, user, and id and then the average:

```
select date, user, avg(max_weigh * 1.0)
from (select date, user, id, max(weight) as max_weigh
      from t
      group by date, user, id
     ) dui
group by date, user;
```

Comment: On any date, per ID there might be records of multiple user actions, which all have assigned different weight. I want to count the sum of these actions by user for all dates, for all the unique IDs. So if he has performed an action with a weight of 0.5 and 0.2 on  certain date for certain ID, it'd only count max weight, which would be 0.5. But if he has also performed another action on the same day on another ID, say with weight of 0.7, the end result that I'd want to see for that date would be 0.7+0.5, which is 1.2

Comment: @Wizy . . . I think that is what this does.